# How do I make something show only on Firefox and Explorer?

Tags: php, cross-browser

I have a link on my page that adds the page to the user's favorites/bookmarks. The problem is that it only works on Explorer or Firefox so I want to add a condition so that it doesn't appear if the user is using Chrome. How do I do it?

This is the code:

```
<a href="#" rel="sidebar" onclick="if(document.all && !window.opera){ window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
return false; }else{ this.title = document.title; }" title="bookmark this page">Agregá esta página a favoritos</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: i believe this would habe to be done in the browser rather than the server, that is, javascript not PHP

Comment: Conversely, perhaps somebody can suggest for you a more cross-browser way to bookmark?  Seems like a better solution to the problem.

Comment: This article may help http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are already using JavaScript object detection to determine the browser. You could continue to use this to either add the link dynamically on page load or set it's *style* to *display none/true*. I would recommend this approach as it keeps everything consistent (client side).

However, if you want to do this with PHP, then check out `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: I second the dynamic approach to checking browser capabilities.  Doing explicit checks for strings like "Firefox" will fail on derivatives, like IceWeasel, Fennec, SeaMonkey, Thunderbird, etc. and that will rapidly become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

there are a plethora of ways to do this via css but this is the easiest

turn off webkit
/** saf3+, chrome1+ **/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { a[rel="sidebar"]{display:none} }